# In The Dirty Dozen is this scene a set up by the officers?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dirty-dozen

In *The Dirty Dozen*, there's a scene where Col. Everett Dasher Breed, played by Robert Ryan, tries to take over command of the Dirty Dozen's operation from Maj. John Reisman [Lee Marvin]. In the end Reisman climbs above the fence with a gun and gets back control of The Dirty Dozen. The outcome is that The Dirty Dozen rally behind Reisman and are pretty much happy campers for the mission.

My question is: was this an organic scene? Or did Maj. John Reisman and Col. Everett Dasher Breed engineer the outcome to get The Dirty Dozen to see Maj. John Reisman as a cool guy who was on their side?

Comment: I was under the impression that the Colonel didn't like the rogue/outlaw/maverick way Maj Reisman operated, and especially resented his mission being outside his chain of command and ability to influence or even get information about.  It's been too long for me to put together an answer without viewing it again. I never got the feeling they were working together, or wanted to, in any way.

Comment: The intent of the scene is as you suggest, but purely for the film makers' dramatic purposes.  The conflict between Reisman (unorthodox-anti authority) and Breed (by the book establishment) is central to the film -- they in no way were working together. This is clearly demonstrated by the war game outcome where Breed is thoroughly embarrassed by the Dirty Dozen squad.